# Cannot get value with size 16. The type encoded as {?={CGPoint=dd}d} is expected to be 24 bytes

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsvalue

This error appears when trying to get a CGPoint from NSValue:

> "Cannot get value with size 16. The type encoded as {?={CGPoint=dd}d} is expected to be 24 bytes"

```
for (NSValue *p in array) {
      CGPoint pointValue = p.CGPointValue; //Here appears this error
}

for (NSValue *p in array) {
      CGPoint pointValue = [p CGPointValue]; //Here appears this error too
}
```

The NSValue is created from a Library and cannot access on it.

**Edit 1**
Printing `p.objCType` results is: `{CGPoint=dd}`

**Edit 2**
Printing array result is:

```
    2021-09-09 16:04:04.251526+0200 App[4964:674948] (
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0xa3b27988de206940eb42b35cc9586740000000000000f03f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0x33b2fe8e136f6840ace8651ab5b967409dc9d7ee7b0bef3f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0xc154b1089cdd6740ace8651ab5b96740b28e3f23264dea3f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0x580edb282aeb6640d62444f11779674016af93916f39e63f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0xf581a96211b865401f0e49e9040867404ded927b8a12e33f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0x1324e1e2ce74644087a474027c66664034f3481fe7b4e13f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0x3523ebef38116340ef3aa01bf3c46540778fc387b583e03f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0x506850e349ee6140777ef255f4f26440e3d77dc1a4b2e13f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0xea7e4c9084db6040ffc14490f52064405e2015fe2ed3e23f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0xfe131ad478f25f40a6b2bdeb801e63401999aea8afcae13f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0x149fdaad30105f4042147f91332c62404e8f96066287e53f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0x1db6515436af5e40ca57d1cb345a6140679349620e80e73f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0x1db6515436af5e40529b230636886040f83000f8e0c2e73f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0x1db6515436af5e409e9f7c15bd8c5f40153010013271e83f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0x0a8863072b715f406fccd347ab495e40869a27450e63e83f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0x71675af0b38a604054179ae54ae65c40a7e25a959d81e53f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0x5cdc9916fc6c6140fb071341d6e35b4069a857606cb8e53f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0xc52270f66d5f62408dda1c31b0015b40d144c5cd8e6ee53f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0xaadd0a035d826340cc346a73c4a05a40b88edb022dbbe43f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0x0d6a3cc975b56440f670484a27605a40ef474c247756e33f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0x6d999b02e2086640f670484a27605a40a01777914c97e23f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0x493dbf68cb8c6740f670484a27605a40b2b27e1fcb90e03f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0x2a9b87e80dd06840cc346a73c4a05a402a0dc7148d2ae33f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0x0cf94f6850136a404f80cfee9b625b4077e1eade1208e33f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0xf0b3ea743f366b40bcadc5fec1445c40538bb556a938e33f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0xdb282a9b87186c403ff92a7a99065d40e0d373bbad4ee63f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0xc9fa3b4e7cda6c40d762ff6022a85d4049ccc22b4fc7e73f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0x3b5889d4f36b6d403072860597aa5e40c7cefa969a66e83f}",
        "{length = 24, bytes = 0xb7cc4d01719c6d40f11739c3820b5f40ac55403eec59ed3f}"
    )
```

**Edit 3**
Note that getting the value in this way:

```
CGPoint pointValue = CGPointMake(0, 0);
[p getValue:&pointValue];
```

Works in Debug mode but crashes in Release.

Comment: Most likely the `NSValue` does not really contain a `CGPoint`. Did you try to print `p.objcType`?

Comment: Question edited: p.objCType print is "{CGPoint=dd}" @Sulthan Thanks you

Comment: One of the things in your list is not a CGPoint. It looks like a block maybe? How did you create this list of NSValues? (Likely if you `NSLog(@"%@", array)`, you'll see the one that's unlike the others.)

Comment: Question edit2: array print produces the given output. @RobNapier

Comment: I meant how are you creating the NSValues, not how are you reading them. The code you've shown here doesn't create an NSValue. These are not what you would get if you created these NSValue objects using `+valueWithCGPoint:`, so I expect you're doing it some other way that's incorrect. Note that `-getValue:` has been deprecated since iOS 11.

Comment: Hi @RobNapier, thanks for your response. Unfortunately the NSValue array is created by an external library. But from docs it's for sure a CGPoint array.

Comment: What is `array`, where it comes from, what's decoded into? Also, all samples in the question have length 24, while the error happens for an item of length 16, so it seems you are not providing all the details.

Comment: `{?={CGPoint=dd}d}` should be a structure that contains a `CGPoint` and an additional `double value`.

Comment: Could you share which library you are using?

Comment: "But from docs it's for sure a CGPoint array." A CGPoint array is not the same thing as an NSArray of NSValues wrapping CGPoints. What, precisely, do the docs say? Clearly something is not what you believe it to be. You need to walk through, one step at a time, and validate each of your assumptions about this data. https://twitter.com/cocoaphony/status/1224364439429881856?s=20

Comment: For us to help you, you need to show us exactly what you're calling, and exactly what the output of that call is. The output you claim for `p.objType` doesn't match the output you claim from the array. So I suspect you're not showing us the exact code you're really using, and we're assuming things about what you're doing that are not true.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct { // just here for reference
   CGFloat x;
   CGFloat y;
} CGPoint; 

struct {
   CGPoint p;
   double d;
} AssumedEntryType;

typedef AssumedEntryType SomeEntry;
```

`d` stays for double.
Looking at your debug print it seems those are 3 values in a struct. So those numbers could represent any data type that fits in 8 byte each (8*3=24).

> Internally NSValue instances consist of a blob of bytes paired with a C-String describing the name and structure of the bytes.

If `{?={CGPoint=dd}d}` is your describing C String of NSValue then you should be able to do the following decoding as a NSValue extension

```objectivec
-(SomeEntry)someEntryValue 
{
    SomeEntry entry;
 
    [self getValue:&entry];
 
    return entry;
}
```

And yes, NSValues can still be collected in NSArray.
Just follow what the C struct description told you.

Ps: not tested code..
Some hints taken from this google search [result](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/11/nsvalue-for-custom-structs/)
or read more at [NSHipster](https://nshipster.com/nsvalue/)

Edit: as Rob pointed out.. 
there are different lists for
[ObjCType](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH100) encodings and [StringFormat](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) Specifiers

And here the NSValue [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Values.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000174-BAJJHDEG)

Comment: In ObjCType notation, `d` is a double, not an int. I think you're confusing NSString /printf format strings for objctype. (`s` is also not `char*`, `*` is.)

Comment: Even better. Because still 8 byte, feel free to edit..